# Show that $\dim(Y)<\infty$, application of the Hahn-Banach theorem.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, open-problem, open-map, hahn-banach-theorem

$\textbf{The question is}$

Let $X,Y$ be a Banach space, $T:X\rightarrow Y$ an surjective linear transformation.

If $\exists D\subseteq Y$ compact: $T(B(0,1))\subseteq D$ then $\dim(Y)<\infty$

$\textbf{Demonstration: suspicion}$

Note that $D\subseteq \bigcup_{y\in D}^{}B(y,1/2)$ Since D is compact, then $\exists y_1,...,y_n \in D: D\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}B(y_i,1/2)$.

In particular $B(0,1)\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}B(y_i,1/2)$ then eliminating the possible $i$ such that $B(0,1)\bigcap B(y_i,1/2)=\emptyset$ and without loss of generality we have that

$B(0,1)\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^{k\leq n}B(y_i,1/2)$.

$\textbf{My question}$

I haven't really accomplished much but my suspicion is that $\left \{y_1,...y_k  \right \} $ is the candidate to be base of $Y$, but I'm kind of stuck with this....

I also believe that T is continuous, and I could apply the Hahn Banach theorem, (T sends open in open) I am also trying to prove this, although I don't know if I can help with this problem.

If someone could guide me to continue, I thank you.

Comment: "Overjective" :) --> should be '*surjective*' I guess. Also, is $T$ assumed to be continuous?

Comment: Hahn-Banach allows to extend continuous linear Functionals. I am not sure how you want to use this here? Also $T$ is clearly continuous since it maps the unit ball into something bounded. In fact, $T$ is even a compact operator. Then your statement means that compact operators can only be surjective if their codomain is finite dimensional. Do you know and can use that a normed space is finite dimensional if and only if the closed unit ball is compact?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $T$ is surjective. The condition $T(B_X(0,1))\subset D,$ where $D$ is compact, implies that $T(B_X(0,1))$ is bounded. Therefore $T$ is a bounded (i.e. continuous) operator. By the open mapping theorem $$T(B(0,1))\supset B_Y(0,r)=rB_Y(0,1)$$ for a number $r>0.$ Thus $B_Y(0,1)$ is relatively compact,hence $Y$ is finite dimensional ([see](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3382249/closed-unit-ball-of-an-infinite-dimensional-banach-space-is-not-compact)).